# Center Form Elements on Page with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've tried every way of centering elements in CSS that I know but I cannot get these form elements to center on the page.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/VJLst/1/

```
<style>
#divQuizFillBlank {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#textQuizFillBlankUserAnswer {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#buttonQuizFillBlankSubmit {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 10%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
</style>

<div id="divQuizFillBlank">
<input type="text" id="textQuizFillBlankUserAnswer">
<input type="button" id="buttonQuizFillBlankSubmit" value="&gt;">
</div>
```

Comment: Give `#divQuizFillBlank` a specific width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You need to set the `width` for `#divQuizFillBlank`.

The rule `margin: auto;` doesn't work for elements without a `width`. Moreover, it works only for `block` elements and those elements take up full available width.

```css
#divQuizFillBlank {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

#### Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/VJLst/2/

Comment: I tried that before but it doesn't look perfectly centered. Check your Fiddle --- there's more space to the right (48px on the left and 81px on the right depending on the size of your window).

Comment: Okay, so you wanna say that you need a perfect fit, right. Gimme a moment, will correct it.

Comment: Your code needed some good tweaking. Check this out now: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/VJLst/7/

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: better way is just margin: 0 auto, that does it in one line...saving space is good :)

Comment: @IlanBiala I have said that in the first line! :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar margin: auto; won't work at all, you need to specify 0 auto for it to work...

Comment: `margin: auto` for the top doesn't matter buddy, I have been doing front end engineering for the past five years, and you can trust me... :)